# For-loop only starts looping in the middle of the list for no reason

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Hi so I have this huge list of lists, let's say list1 is a list of size 1024

When I do a for-loop, the loop somehow starts in the middle and loop to the end. Apparently it ignores the first half of the list for no reason.

For example, if I do a simple for-loop over list1:

```
for i in list1:
    print(i)
```

It gives me

```
[135, 14, 16]
[139, 15, 16]
[131, 16, 16]
[135, 17, 16]
...
...
[167, 28, 31]
[159, 29, 31]
[150, 30, 31]
[140, 31, 31]
```

So the first half is missing for no reason.

When I check it by doing:

```
print(list1)
```

It gives me the whole list without any problem, so I have no idea what's going on here. Is it because the list is too big?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Oh it's python. Sorry, I should've added that description.

Comment: Where and how is `list1` defined?

Comment: It started as an empty list and it appended the results from the last for-loop over something else.

Comment: Currently your problem isn't reproducible. How do you know the "first half" is missing? Are you sure the order of the inner lists is what you think it is?

Comment: Are you printing to the terminal? Did you scroll up?

Comment: It can be easily seen on variable explorer too. I made sure of it, trust me.

Comment: So you're attempting to print 1024 lines. Is it possible your terminal is only able to show the last 500 lines, cutting off any output from before that?

Comment: Try piping your output to `less`: `python3 myprog.py | less`. (This might not work on Windows.)

Comment: Yeah it does seem like the console is just too small for this task. (It won't show you the whole list even when you scroll up to the max) When I create an empty list and append i, the new list does have the complete set of elements. This is extremely weird!! Well, now I know. Thanks, guys!!

Comment: @JohnZhou Depending on your console, you change the buffer size to show more lines.

Answer (score 2):

Given that one difference between your `for` loop and your basic `print` is that the latter will most certainly have more items per line, it could be a line limit problem on the output window (likely a Linux terminal, Window console, or a console within an IDE, depending on your development set-up).

If, when you scroll to the first line of your shortened output, your vertical scroll bar indicates it's at the top of the scroll-back buffer, that's probably the case. You can also validate this with a single print but reverting to one item per line, and seeing if the problem still exists. In other words:

```py
print("\n".join(list1)) # All items but with newline between each.
```

You can also confirm that the list contains the quantity of elements you expect, with `print(len(list1))`. And, to ensure they're all being printed even if there's a scrolling limitation, use something like:

```
python myprog.py | wc -l         # Count lines (UNIX-y).
python myprog.py | find /v /c "" # Count lines (Windows).

python myprog.py | less          # Page output (UNIX-y).
python myprog.py | more          # Page output (Windows).
```

That should make it *far* clearer if the output is correct but your output window is not large enough to hold all the data.

So you *could* change your output window to hold more lines. Terminal programs under Linux, and the various consoles under Windows, generally allow for this. But, since there will probably *always* be an output size that will exceed your output window, it might be better of getting used to using `less/more`.